# How Does Member Enumeration Work in PowerShell 3?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In PoweShell 2 we did:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Sort-Object
```

In Powershell 3 we do:

```
(Get-ChildItem).LastWriteTime | Sort-Object
```

But how does it work, i read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) blog post on MSDN and they say that its faster because the foreach loop isnt running? So how does it enumerate the properties then ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PowerShell is doing the hard work for us and it loops over the collection internally. I like to call this "implicit foreach". Assuming the member you specified is present on each object, if the member you specified is a property, you get back its value. If it's a method, it invokes the method on the each object.

In v2, to get all process names you had to take care of looping yourself:

```
Get-Process | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```

In v3, the equivalent would be:

```
(Get-Process).Name
```

Same applies to methods. To kill all processes with name starting with note*:

```
(Get-Process note*).Kill()
```

Comment: great answer, i never knew about that it worked for methods as well. That's awesome. I wonder how much faster it is.

Answer (score 0):

The blog says foreach-object cmdlet is not running. Now it is taken care of by the language engine and not a cmdlet, making it faster. How it EXACTLY works is internal implementation detail and I think that is not what you really want to know.