# Powershell: Find number of occurrences of a specific numeric value from an integer array

Tags: arrays, powershell, integer

I have an integer array like below and I wanted to count number of 1's in that array in powershell, Can anyone help me here please,

```
[array]$inputs = 81,11,101,1811,1981
$count = 0
foreach($input in $inputs)
{       
Write-Host "Processing element $input"
$count += ($input -like "*1*" | Measure-Object).Count 
}
Write-Host "Number of 1's in the given array is $count"
```

It gives me only 5 1's in that array but expected answer is 10. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a side note:

> **Don't use [`$Input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#input)** as a custom variable as it is a preserved automatic variable

**For what you are trying:**
You iterating trough an array and check whether each item (with will automatically type cast to a string) is [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-like) a `1` preceded by any number of characters and succeeded by any number of characters which is either true or false (and not the total number of ones in the string).

**Instead**
You might want to use the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet with the `-AllMatches` switch which counts all the matches:

```
[array]$inputs = 81,11,101,1811,1981
$count = 0
foreach($i in $inputs)
{       
Write-Host "Processing element $input"
$count += ($i | Select-String 1 -AllMatches).Matches.Count 
}
Write-Host "Number of 1's in the given array is $count"
```

In fact, thanks to the PowerShell [member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133329/1701026) feature, you do not even have to iterate through each array item for this, and just simplify it to this:

```
[array]$inputs = 81,11,101,1811,1981
$count = ($Inputs | Select-String 1 -AllMatches).Matches.Count
Write-Host "Number of 1's in the given array is $count"
```

```
Number of 1's in the given array is 10
```

Comment: Please [decide if the answer is helpful, and then...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and suggestion. It works also I have solved this issue with below script, Is it a right approach,

[string]$inputs = 89,89,99,909,9899,9989,9.09
$count = 0
foreach($i in $inputs.ToCharArray())
{  
    if($i -eq "9")   
    {$count++}  
 
}
Write-Host "Number of 9's in the given array is $count"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue with below script,

```
[string]$inputs = 81,11,101,1811,1981
$count = 0
foreach($i in $inputs.ToCharArray())
{  
    if($i -eq "1")   
    {$count++}  
 
}
Write-Host "Number of 1's in the given array is $count"
```