# How to extract properties from a powershell object

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, get-childitem

I am trying to extract properties of object from the results obtained from Get-ChildItem in Powershell as it may be seen below

```
$folderPath = "C:\Users\me\someThing1\someThing2"
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem  -Path $folderPath -Filter *.pdf -recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.FullName  
    $_.LastWriteTime
    $_.Exists
    $_.BaseName
    $_.Extension
}
# Extracting properties
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    Write-Host $file
  
}
```

When I use the Write-Host command,  I get property values of FullName, LastWriteTime, Exists, BaseName, Extension printed to the terminal for each file. But I am unable to get individual property value.

For e.g., I tried

```
Write-Host $file."BaseName"
```

It does not work. Can someone help me extract individual property from each file?
The purpose is to store each property of each file into an array as given below

```
$FullNames = @()
$LastWriteTimes  = @()
$Exists = @()
$BaseNames  = @()
$Extensions  = @()
```

Comment: Remove ForEach-Object completely

Comment: Yup. You also don't need to save each property on each of those arrays. i.e: after you do `$fileNames = Get-ChildItem  -Path $folderPath -Filter *.pdf -recurse` the "FullName" of all your files will be here `$fileNames.FullName`, the "lastWriteTime" will be here `$fileNames.lastWriteTime` and so on.

Comment: These 2 are correct. Also, even tho it's not needed in this case, you should try swapping to an `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instead of a fixed array when saving output.

Comment: In addition, `Write-Host` is almost always not good to use. If you want to cast a property to your PS Host you can just do `$file.BaseName` inside your `foreach` loop or if you need a string you can do `"Base Name: {0}" -f $file.BaseName` or `"Base Name: $($file.BaseName)"`

Comment: Thank you All. You have been super helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Does Member Enumeration Work in PowerShell 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131416/how-does-member-enumeration-work-in-powershell-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posting the revised code that extracts properties into individual arrays just so that someone else might find it helpful. Thanks to all who supported.

```
# Edit the Folder Path as desired
$folderPath = "C:\Users\me\someThing1\someThing2"

# Getting File Objects
$files = Get-ChildItem  -Path $folderPath -recurse 
   

# Extracting properties into individual Arrays
$FullNames = $files.FullName
$LastWriteTimes = $files.LastWriteTime
$file_Exists = $files.Exists
$BaseNames = $files.BaseName
$Extensions = $files.Extension
```

Comment: There is no need for the foreach loop or declaring those arrays. Just try `$FullNames = $files.FullName` and see for yourself :)

Comment: Cool. I never knew that it was so easy to get info from powershell! Thanks again. I updated the answer too by simplifying it.

Comment: Yeap, PS is like Python with helping wheels.

Comment: You don't even need to extract them into individual arrays.  Just use the properties of the $files object as the arrays

Comment: The is called [member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133329/1701026).