# PowerShell - Select only the value (true/false) instead of the complete object itself

Tags: powershell, active-directory, admin

I am currently developing and consolidating my PowerShell skills and needed help for my script.

I want to retrieve only the result / value "true / false" of the object rather than the description followed by the result of value "true / false".

It will be clearer with my code :

```
$moreadlock = get-aduser -identity fferman -properties * | select lastbadpasswordattempt, lastlogondate, lockedout, passwordexpired, passwordlastset | format-list

    $sAMAccountName = Read-Host "Username"
        if ( $null -ne ([ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$sAMAccountName)").FindOne() -eq $true ) {
Write-Host "Exist."
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Additional information about the selected user : "    
$moreadlock
```

**AND at this level, I would like to implement a condition :
If the value of "lockedout" is true, propose an unblocking of the account in the AD**

```
        if ( $lockedout -eq $true ) {
Write-Host "Account locked."
```

With, after asking the user something like that :

```
$qunlock = Read-Host "Unlock account ?"
    if ( $qunlock -eq $true ) {
    Unlock-AdAccount }
```

The problem being that using the command:

```
$test=get-aduser -identity user -properties * | Select-Object -Property lockedout
$test
```

This returns me:

```
lockedout
---------
    False
```

**And not the result of the value itself, "false".**

Comment: `(get-aduser -identity user -properties *).lockedout` (called [member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131416/how-does-member-enumeration-work-in-powershell-3))

Comment: INstead of `Select-Object -Property lockedout` do `Select-Object -ExpandProperty lockedout`

Comment: As in @Olaf 's comment, **don't use** `-Properties *`. It is wasteful and time consuming to ask for **ALL** properties where you really only need one.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

Please use the below command to get the value of the LockedOut of an AD user :

```
Get-ADUser -Identity "labadmin" -properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty lockedout
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution that I have chosen to implement.**

```
Write-Host "Is the account blocked : " -ForegroundColor gray -NoNewline
(get-aduser -identity $ADuser -properties *).lockedout
```

*(get me *all the properties of $ADuser account).select the value of this property*

[*Is the account blocked - example*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJxRT.png)